# Open source Ecommerce with a rest API

Tags: gratis, open-source, php, ecommerce, rest

I'm looking for

1. Fully open source, self hosted Ecommerce platform (no hidden fees or things that can't be done except by paying lots of money)
2. Not Magentoo, and not written in nodejs, and not woocommerce, I still don't trust Wordpress' rest api
3. Well documented and active community, some place I can get help from.
4. Preferably: in PHP, supports many databases, primarily MariaDB.
5. Has to run on Linux so no .net
6. Must have a clear, easy to learn, full featured REST API because I will use the platform as a backend for a mobile application.
7. Must have many fully responsive themes, plugins and must support many payment gateways because where I'm from Paypal isn't available
8. Would be nice if large companies already using it, just to make sure it can scale with no problems and that it is pretty secure and has no major bugs.
9. Must supports multiple stores and multiple vendors.